# Find a subdivision of K4 in the Grötzsch graph.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

It is known that the Grötzsch graph is 4-coloring.

Hence it contains a subdivision of K4.

But where is this subdivision?

[image: the Grötzsch graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a is joined to b, e, f.

b is joined to e via j, and to f via h and k.

e is joined to f via g.

So a, b, e, f is a $K_4$, subdivided at j, h, k, and g.